# Oracle impdb command throws ORA-12154 error, but sqlplus and sql developer are working properly

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration, impdp

I installed oracle 12c freshly in windows computer and created a new database service. It initially was not recognized by the `Oracle SQL Developer`, but after I reconfigure the default listener `Oracle SQL Developer` and `SQLPlus` were connected to the database service.

But when I tried to import a DB dump using `impdb` command, repeatedly I got the following error.

```
UDI-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154 
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

[image: sql developer connection status]

[image: windows services]

The import command -

```
impdp system/password@ORCL schemas=mline directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DUMP_V005.DMP logfile=DUMP_V005_LOG.log;
```

I will be grateful if you could help me to solve this issue. (Please note that I am relatively a beginner in the context of oracle installation process.)

Comment: Your SQL Developer connection is not using TNS. SQL\*Plus is probably using a bequeath connection, which also doesn't involve TNS. The error means you don't have an alias called "ORCL" in your `tnsnames.ora` file. Check what that file contains, and add an alias if there isn't one already. Or use Easy Connect syntax - but you need the service name, not the SID, for that.